# How can I fix a “Cannot communicate with battery” error on Canon T6s?

Tags: canon, battery, error

I have the same problem described in the following question but for the Canon T6s:

[How can I fix a "Cannot communicate with battery" error on Canon 7D?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/how-can-i-fix-a-cannot-communicate-with-battery-error-on-canon-7d)

I think it is just a loose screw since it sounds when I move the camera back and forward.

However, the construction of the camera is different and can't find a service manual to guide the process of disassembling.

Anyone with experience on technical service for this model? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Before you go tearing your camera apart be sure the the sound you hear isn't inside the pop up flash, which has a rattle inside that is perfectly normal when the flash is stored in the down position.

Comment: Are you using a Canon battery or a third party clone? Have you tried a different battery? Have you tried the same battery in a different camera?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelClark, I will pay attention to the flash.

Comment: Yes, I have tested the camera with other original batteries and have the same problem.

Comment: Not sure if the sound comes from the flash, it is very subtle. It is still present when the flash is open.

Comment: Please see page 391 of the *EOS Rebel T6s Instruction Manual*: http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300018244/01/eos-rebelt6s-760d-im-en.pdf

Comment: I guess you're right, according to the manual: "A small noise may be heard when the camera’s internal mechanism moves slightly."

Comment: I got the same problem 2 days ago with my T6S when shooting during a snowfall. Same error with 2 original batteries. I found many people having similar issues with an older model (70d I think). It seems that the cold weather (1 Celsius I think) triggered it. The camera is less than 6 months old. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple batteries exhibit the same problems, then either the electronics that talk to the battery have failed or the communication contacts have some pocket lint stuck to them.  My money would be on the latter.  Try wiping them with an alcohol-covered swab.

If that doesn't help, just know that it isn't a fatal problem.  You can ignore it. The camera is capable of checking the battery voltage and doing approximately the right thing even if communication isn't working; it might shut down earlier to avoid the risk of a partial shot write, but otherwise, AFAIK, the problem is ignorable.

Or you could get a grip, so your batteries will use a whole different set of contacts that probably don't use the same I2C bus or whatever it is.